# Function registered with atexit() not getting called

Tags: c++, c, freebsd, atexit

Is it guaranteed that a function registered with atexit will ALWAYS be called upon normal program termination? (I encounterd a scenario in FreeBSD where a function that I register with atexit never gets called, even when the program terminates normally).

Comment: An application that calls `_exit(2)` rather than `exit(3)` will bypass the exit handlers, and it might _look_ like a normal termination from outside the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  First, the function will not be called if `atexit` returns a non-0 value.  Secondly, it won't be called if a function registered before it doesn't return normally.

Comment: Registered functions are called in reverse order of registration.  James, you probably mean "if a function registered after it doesn't return normally".

Comment: @Bill Evans Yes.  I was thinking of the order the functions are called.

Comment: @JamesKanze Is there any alternative to `atexit` that will cover abnormal termination?

Answer (score 1):

What do you call "normal termination"?

Unix and C99 have functions _Exit (both POSIX and C99) and _exit (only POSIX) which allow to terminate a program with whatever status you want and without running the atexit handlers.  The other cases I know where they aren't run all clearly fail into the "abnormal termination" bucket.